# Where can I track the current commit running on devnet?

Tags: devnet

I'm trying to figure out if https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/28217/files#diff-b55d9bcb5d2e7eae09fd352edcc765f9c2a4c05b97e9847582071d35850e8671 has been deployed to devnet.
Can someone help me figure out where I can find that informat

Answer (score 1):

You can use `solana feature status` to get the currently active features